# Force the -vm entry in the eclipse.ini to stay as relative path?

Tags: eclipse, startup, ini

There was a bug where after installing plugins the -vm entry got messed up. This is a bit similar, on every run the relative path will get resolved into an absolute path. I would like to keep the eclipse portable and this is the last part required to make this happen. When the path gets resolved into absolute it again is not portable. Is there a way to stop eclipse from resolving the -vm entry? Or disallow touching the INI file at all?

If not I will have to use separate cmd to start the eclipse or use a shortcut and feed the -vm that way.

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Edit: The desire is to have portable Eclipse with bundled JRE and have it working even when it's moved around.

Comment: This event is only triggered when I move the eclipse's folder. And then on the consecutive run the path will be resolved into absolute.

Comment: Instead of using `-vm` you can embed a JRE/SDK in the subfolder `jre` of your Eclipse installation folder.

Comment: That works pretty well, I think I will go with that. And yet again, you technically didn't answer exactly the question and yet again solved my problem perfectly (I want portable eclipse and this achieves it). Do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @howlger sorry to bother you, but we are doing a Java application and would like to reuse the same jre we bundle with Eclipse, by any chance do you know from top of your head what mechanism in the java launchers allows it to use the relative path jre subfolder instead of the system wide java?

Comment: Or just the binary invokes 'java -jar given.jar' with the relative path as prefix before the java binary?

Comment: Yes, `"path/to/eclipse/jre/bin/java" -jar  given.jar` should work (`JAVA_HOME` does not need to be set).

Comment: Thank you and I forgot just setting the PATH and forcing your path to java as precedence should work too. For some reason I was not comprehending that Java is nothing magical it's just another binary in the system, which is under a path. I was not sure about the JAVA_HOME, so just to be sure I did set it up. But when you are saying it's not needed I should actually read up properly what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exact answer to your question, but to get a portable Eclipse IDE or an Eclipse-based application, a **JRE/SDK can be embedded in the subfolder `jre`** instead of using `-vm` in the `.ini` file.

Comment: You help me resolve so many issues already. Are you wondering what will be the final result? Would you interested to see the final product when it's done?

Comment: Yeah, I'd be interested. :-)

Comment: OK, I will let you know when it will be finished.